# HP laptop (Windows 7 x64) turns itself on @11:30am every day

Tags: windows-7, sleep, scheduled-tasks, wake-up

My HP laptop wakes up from sleep every day at 11:30am by itself. No tasks scheduled for that time (either user or Windows tasks).

No AV scans or updates scheduled for that time. Auto-defrag & auto-diagnostics disabled. In the Event Viewer, under Security, I see entries such as "Microsoft Security Audit" around 11:30am, but I see similar entries at other times, at about the same frequency.

Is there a log in Windows 7 where I could see what SPECIFIC process requested that the laptop be awakened at a given time?

Answer (score 2):

Check if it also wakes up automatically from being completely shut down. If so, there is probably a BIOS option configured to automatically turn it on. If this is the case, enter the BIOS setup by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> (for most HP laptops) when booting up, and look for a scheduled wake-up time.

If it doesn't wake from complete shutdown, some process is waking it up then. Are you sure you've checked all of the scheduled tasks? There can be multiple folders in the task scheduler which it would be in. Is there a backup program running?

You could also use software like SysInternals [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to look at what processes are launching right at 11:30am. If a certain process runs every day right at that time, that would be a clue to what is causing the problem.

You could also just dump the running process list by running `tasklist > file.txt` at 11:29 and 11:31. This will create a text file with a list of all the processes running. You could then DIFF these files to see what is running which wasn't before. If you'd like to load the lists into Excel to make it easier to analyze, you can use `tasklist /FO CSV > file.txt` to dump a csv file which can be imported into Excel.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try listing processes at 11:29 and 11:31. The only problem I see is that the list may contain cryptic entries like "svchost.exe", all active prior to the wake-up. If any of them woke up my laptop, I won't be able to tell. Things would be so much easier if the Event Viewer could just tell me the NAME of the SPECIFIC PROCESS which triggered the last wake event. I see tons of usesless info there, except this crucial detail.

Comment: Nothing in the BIOS related to wake-up time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Event Viewer](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2010/02/event-viewer-in-windows-7-and-vista.html) logs?

Comment: Already answered in the original question.