# Windows doesn't put computer to sleep or turn it off after turning it on for maintenance

Tags: windows-8, boot, sleep, windows-8.1, maintenance

I've configured Windows to turn my computer on during the night to perform maintenance:

[image: "Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time" is turned on]

However, I've found that after it does this and finishes maintenance, it doesn't put the computer to sleep, hibernate it, or turn it off. I sometimes get up in the morning and find the computer on doing nothing.

I've confirmed that the power settings are set to cause it to go to sleep or hibernate after a very short amount of time:

[image: Power settings set to cause the computer to sleep after a few minutes]

I'm concerned about this because I think Windows is wasting electricity and therefore my money by leaving the computer on doing nothing. How can I allow it to turn the computer on at night for maintenance but also turn it off or at least put it to sleep when it's finished?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a few ways, this approach seems most simple,

Press: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> →  Type: Taskschd.msc > <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Task Scheduler is open, you can right-click on "Task Scheduler
(Local)" that appears at the top of the list on the left. Consider adding task to this location \Microsoft\Windows\TaskSchedulerOnce
Then, choose "Create Basic Task."

Enter a name of the task ("Shutdown") > Next. 
Determine to length of time computer should be on for maintenance, 20 mins to a hour should be sufficient.

Enter when you want the shutdown task to start (time after maintenance runs) > Next.

Choose "Start a program" > Next.

Under "Program/script:" type "shutdown" and next to "Add arguments (optional):" type "/s"

That's all

For more details see [this article](http://library.techguy.org/wiki/How_to:_Schedule_computer_to_turn_on_and_off_automatically).

Here is a [similar question with more depth](https://superuser.com/questions/497983/windows-8-waking-issues-maintenance-configurator-task-cannot-be-changed-or-d).