# Why is Windows 8 waking up my computer unexpectedly?

Tags: windows-8, sleep, wake-on-lan

I decided to finally install Windows 8 on one of my desktop computers. It's Windows 8.1 Pro from the get-go, and I got the Update 1 through Windows Update. It works fine. But my main concern right now is that it wakes up my computer after I put it to sleep. I put it to sleep by pressing the sleep button on my keyboard.

There is a Microsoft KB article about this.

> [Windows 8 desktop wakes up unexpectedly from sleep or hibernation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799178)
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> A Windows 8 Desktop computer is automatically waking from sleep or
>   hibernation at a certain time even if there is no "ACPI Wake Alarm"
>   system device found by the operating system.
>
> **Cause**
>
> For Windows 8 desktops or All-in-one computers, under Action Center /
>   Automatic Maintenance, the checkbox is automatically enabled for
>   “Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled
>   time”. Also, the power policy / Advanced settings / Sleep / Allow wake
>   timers will default to Enabled for AC power.
>
> If the desktop machine does not have an “ACPI Wake Alarm” device (or
>   if it is disabled in the BIOS), Windows 8 still uses the Real Time
>   Clock (RTC) to program wake events, assuming the power policy /
>   Advanced settings / Sleep / Allow wake timers is Enabled for AC power.

What's ACPI Wake Alarm device?... I could not locate the "Automatic Maintenance" option.

[image: action center]
[image: action center]

The option "Allow wake timers" is enabled in Power Options dialog.

[image: power options]

But the `powercfg /waketimers` command says there are no wake timers.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /waketimers
There are no active wake timers in the system.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

So these options should not matter then, right?

I think it's my network card that wakes up my computer. But why would it do that? I do have WOL (Wake-On-LAN) enabled and I use that occasionally. I had Windows 7 Ultimate before installing Windows 8, and I think I had to enable this feature in BIOS and then in Device Manager. But I think this is set as enabled by default now in Windows 8. So I didn't touch any of those settings. Here's what I found in the System log.

[image: power-troubleshooter]

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T21:08:30.188798700Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T21:17:41.262988300Z

Wake Source: Device -Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

I believe this is from the last time it woke up unexpectedly. I normally use my mouse to wake up the computer. As I searched through the log, I found that there is an unknown wake source. Here are the last few wake up events.

```
#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T23:27:22.259006200Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎14T09:07:34.293661300Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T21:08:30.188798700Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T21:17:41.262988300Z

Wake Source: Device -Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T09:56:49.947590500Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T10:50:19.258919900Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎12T23:16:11.122616600Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎13T07:27:49.265183700Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎12T09:09:38.868040700Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎12T14:56:44.339231700Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎11T23:22:44.847600700Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎12T08:26:27.666880800Z

Wake Source: Unknown

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎11T15:04:01.090698200Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎11T16:02:54.300287300Z

Wake Source: Unknown

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎10T23:35:46.989285000Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎11T09:14:49.250228900Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎10T23:09:06.024062600Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎10T23:30:08.602710700Z

Wake Source: Device -USB Root Hub

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎10T09:56:17.923592700Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎10T17:26:14.339458100Z

Wake Source: Unknown

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎09T23:22:05.363064000Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎10T09:26:32.681954100Z

Wake Source: Unknown

#
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎09T23:12:43.624651300Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎09T23:18:16.367444900Z

Wake Source: Device -Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

How can I get more information about this unknown device? How can the system not know what woke it up? And if it is my network card that wakes it up, why would it do that? I didn't have this problem with Windows 7. But now I do with Windows 8 (8.1 Update 1), on the same computer.

**Update**

---

In the properties dialog box for the network card in Device Manager, **Wake on Magic Packet** is enabled, as is **Wake on pattern match** under the Advanced tab.

[image: magic packet]
[image: power management]

But there is the option **Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer** under the Power Management tab, and it's disabled. I will try enabling this. But isn't this for computers that have more than one network interface?

It just woke up a few hours ago.

```
The system has returned from a low power state.

Sleep Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎14T12:08:53.237475400Z
Wake Time: ‎2014‎-‎09‎-‎14T12:17:48.289129900Z

Wake Source: Device -Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

So it is indeed my network card that's waking it. But why? What triggers it? I didn't send any WoL packets to it. Not that I'm aware of anyway. I usually use my router to send WoL commands, and I have not port forwarded WoL, so it should only work locally. It shouldn't be able to wake up over the Internet.

Comment: +1 Your question actually answered something I was wondering about for a while, thanks. :) Btw, is your WoL set to use Magic Packet, or could it be triggered by a broadcasted WoL for another device?

Comment: Check Task Scheduler.  Everyone and his brother throws a task in there to check for updates of XYZ tool.  Sometimes they do it several times a day.

Comment: @Peter Yeah? :) What's that? In the properties dialog box for the network card in Device Manager, "Wake on Magic Packet" is enabled, as is "Wake on pattern match" under Advanced tab. Does this help? But there is the option "Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer" under the Power Management tab, and it's ticked off.

Comment: @Peter I have posted an update to my question. See the screenshots? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about the settings (that's why I commented rather than answered), but I know that WoL can be enabled to only wake the PC if a Magic Packet containing the MAC address of the network card is received (that's what typical home users want and need), or WoL can be configured to work under "other circumstances" as well. Only I never bothered with these other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Windows 8 for Automatic Maintenance.

Press WindowsKey + W, type "maintenance" > select "Change Automatic Maintenance Settings". Here you will see that the Win8 system has a default setting of 03:00am as well as "Allow scheduled maintenance to wake my computer".

Answer (score 0):

See [answer](https://superuser.com/a/503802/117691) to my question: windows 8 desktop wakes up immediately after sleep due to keyboard/mouse